# Unable to alter SQL using PDO statement

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

```
if (isset($_GET['ResetPassword']))  { 
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $sql = "ALTER LOGIN $name WITH PASSWORD=N'Nico1234!'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_GET['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Hi guys I cant alter the password of a certain name(user) Where the name is from get (Selected from the sql).
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you binding when your SQL has no placeholders to bind against...? You're probably getting errors, check your logs.

Comment: Update is for Tables and Since User is different type of Object, that's why i used ALTER

Comment: Your sql does not have any placeholdres but you are binding?

Comment: `<a href="reset.php?userid='.$rows['name'].'" class="btn btn-sucess btn-sm" role="button">Reset</a>`

Comment: I see (microsoft are really the worst for using common keywords for their exotic syntax), then you still have the `N` outside of the string here `=N'Nico1234!'` and the binding problem

Comment: `$sql ="UPDATE LOGIN SET PASSWORD ='Nico1234!' WHERE name=:name";`
`$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);`
`$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_GET['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);`                                              
`$stmt->execute(); `

I have tried to use this but not updating as well

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE Statements are used for changing the schema of a Table like adding a Column or FOREIGN KEYS.
Are you trying to make an UPDATE Statement? The right query would be:

```
"UPDATE Login SET PASSWORD='Nico1234!' WHERE name=:name"
```

If you want to add the `$_GET['name']` Parameter to the statement, you have to use `:name` anywhere inside it.

Comment: `$sql ="UPDATE LOGIN SET PASSWORD ='Nico1234!' WHERE name=:name";`
`$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);` 
`$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_GET['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);`                                        
`$stmt->execute();` 

I have followed your statement but it is still not updating. :(

Comment: Maybe you can add the CREATE-Statement(s) of the Table to check other errors

Comment: I already have selected the names from the database so i think there is no need to create?

Comment: I meant add it in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the properties of a SQL Server login account, use [ALTER LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
The problem here will be the parameter in your statement. 
Table and column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. I'm not sure, but I think that it's the same for login names. 
So, in this case, you should use statement without parameters, escape special characters and sanitize the data manually.

As a note, when you want to use a parameter, the correct syntax for a placeholder is `:name` or `?`, not `$name`.

```
<?php
...
try {
   # SQL Authentication
   $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);
   # Windows Authentication
   #$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database");
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
   die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}

...
try {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $password = 'Nico1234!';
    # Escape special characters and do some check for $name and $password values 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("ALTER LOGIN $name WITH PASSWORD = N'$password'");
    $stmt->execute();
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die("Error executing query: ".$e->getMessage() );
}
...
?>
```

`ALTER LOGIN` needs permissions to execute correctly. If you use Windows authentication, then the Web server's process identity or thread identity (if the Web server is using impersonation) is used to connect to the SQL Server. Use next script for more information (change between SQL and Window authentication):

```
<?php
# Connection
$server    = 'server\instance,port';
$database  = 'database';
$uid       = 'uid';
$pwd       = 'pwd';

# PDO Connection
try {
    # SQL authentication
    #$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);
    # Windows authentication
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}

# 
try {
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT 'SUSER_SNAME' AS [NAME], CONVERT(nvarchar(128), SUSER_SNAME()) AS [VALUE]");
    # Data
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        echo $row['NAME'].": ".$row['VALUE']."</br>";
    }    
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error executing query".$e->getMessage() );
}

#
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: the query is not altering, with no error. I think it has to do with the $_GET['name']; the name is getting a value of 'sa' not the name itself (nico) even if i select and use same variable.

Comment: @NicoGestiada Please, check updated answer. There are some things to consider: 1) Set error handling to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;  2) Try to find why your `$_GET['name']` is set to `sa`; 3) ALTER LOGIN needs permissions.